# The Length of Data is invalid while decrypting a txt file

Tags: c#

I made a console app to decrypt a file .  Please refer to the screenshot for detail error message.

If you copy paste the code in a console app . You should be able to debug .

1) Need to make folder SourceFolder\Newfolder\ and a new txt file destination.txt

2) Need to make folder for C:\DestinationFolder\source.txt(encrypted file cannot attach file here i hope you can make one

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
    //SALT is a random data that is used as addition to a password to encrypt data
    // The primary function is to protect against lists of often used password
    private static readonly byte[] SALT = new byte[] {0x26,0xdc,0xff,0x76,0x76,
                                                            0xad,0xed,0x7a,0x64,0xc5,0xfe
                                                            ,0x20,0xaf,0x4d,0x08,0x3c};

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Need to make a SourceFolder and but the file in there abc.txt
        string path = @"C:\SourceFolder\New folder\";
        string[] txtFile = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
        string fileinnn = txtFile[0];



        //Get the filepath of the decrypted file. Need to make this folder and add a new file that is what i am donig for now for this cosole app 
        string filepathDecrypted = @"C:\DestinationFolder\destination.txt";  //this is a new file need to create

        //Get the password 
        string encrytionKey = "password.";
        Decrypt(fileinnn, filepathDecrypted, encrytionKey);
    }

    public static void Decrypt(string fileIn, string fileOut, string Password)
    {
        //open filestreat for encrypted source file
        using (System.IO.FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(fileIn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            using (System.IO.FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(fileOut, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                try
                {
                    //Create Key and IV from the password with the SALT 
                    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdf = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password, SALT);

                    //Create a symmetric algorithm with Rijndael
                    Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();

                    alg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    //alg.BlockSize = 128;


                    //SET key and IV 
                    alg.Key = pdf.GetBytes(32);
                    alg.IV = pdf.GetBytes(16);
                    //Create a cryptoStream 

                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOut, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        //Intialize the buffer and process the input in chunks 
                        // this is done to avoid reading the whole file which is huge and memory consumption. 

                        int bufferLen = 4096;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                        int bytesRead;
                        do
                        { //read a chunck of data from the input file 
                            bytesRead = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);

                            //Decrypt it 
                            cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                        while (bytesRead != 0);

                        //close everything 
                        cs.Close();   //this is where it throws exception
                        fsOut.Close();
                        fsIn.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var error = ex.Message;

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Error message that i am getting** 
[image]

Comment: Show the encryption method as well.

Comment: If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Comment: Hint: Stream.CopyTo would remove a bunch of your code.

Comment: i had a encryted file that was given to me to decrypt it . A third party gives the file in a location. My job was to decrypt these file. hence running into this issue. I am not sure how they encrypt it. Please let me know if i am missing anything. I will try my best to give you all the details. thank you

Comment: _I am not sure how they encrypt it._ ?? There is more then 1 method of encryption. If you do not know what they use, you need to crack it. Much luck with that.

Comment: The reason I ask you to show the encryption code (and I understand now that you don't have it) is that it's just as likely there is a bug in that code as there is in the decryption code, as long as you're writing both. Is the third party able to decrypt the file? Do you know that the file is in fact OK? If you're not sure how to encrypt it, how sure are you that you got all the details of the decryption right?

Comment: And no, obviously we cannot make a file for testing your code as that would entail encrypting some data the exact same way the third party did it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code per se, if the file had been encrypted using the same algorithm and settings. Since it doesn't decrypt with those settings, it cannot have been encrypted using those settings either. You need to go back to your third party and ask for clarification. The reason I can say this is that I took your code and created a matching encryption function, and successfully encrypted and then decrypted a file. The code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/lassevk/98d278d9a74cf415de8a19aac8e65672

Comment: thank you very much for all your help .